# PHP Нету текста в теге

Tags: php, парсер

```
$result = file_get_contents("http://pogoda.ee");
preg_match( '/<td id="L_R_tl".?(.*?)<\/td>/is', $result , $links );
print_r($links);
```

на сайте есть текст в теге а в file get contents нет
как сделать так что бы не было пусто в теге

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На том сайте контент в тег попадает с помощью jQuery после загрузки страницы. На php этого никак не сделать. Попробуйте использовать или другой сайт или api.

Comment: @NoProgress как уже сказано в ответе контент попадает на страницу через `AJAX`. Но AJAX то между делом получает данные у [по известным URL](http://pogoda.ee/sisu/2015/json_eesti_linnade_ilm.php3?l=0) поэтому вас в целом даже парсер писать не надо. Можете просто получить готовый JSON и работать с ним.

Comment: по ф12 видно что 3 `ajax` запроса выполняются. Разберитесь где что, и все дела.

Comment: Это в случае с кросдоменными запросами работает ?

Comment: кросс-доменные запросы вызывают проблему, когда запрос выполняет сам ajax, автор же его выполняет с помощью php, поэтому ограничений тут никаких не будет.

Comment: хм, возможно вы правы, но так сильно заморачиваться ради парсинга html ? я бы попробовал какое нибудь апи вместо curl + json + regexp

Comment: вы в целом правильно написали, что надо использовать API. Вот ссылки ([раз](http://pogoda.ee/sisu/2015/json_eesti_linnade_ilm.php3?l=0), [два](http://pogoda.ee/sisu/2015/json_avakaart.php3?), [три](http://pogoda.ee/sisu/2015/json_reaal_linn.php3?linn=L*tallinn*2), [четыре](http://pogoda.ee/sisu/2015/json_linnailm.php3?linn=L*tallinn*2)) по которым сайт сам и обращается к себе самому через ajax при загрузке страницы, и есть API. Его и надо юзать напрямую. `curl`  тут будет перебором, ибо спокойно данные можно получить через `file_get_contents()`.

Comment: и никакого парсинга html соответственно тоже не будет.